# Include double quote output if a variable is a string

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way automatically to include double quote if a variable is a string?

For example:

`const test = "100";`

If a `test` is a string then output (eg: `console.log`): `"100"`

I would like `console.log(test)` to be `"100"` instead of `100`

Comment: No clue what you are asking.... You want console.log() to change what it outputs?

Answer (score 1):

You could test and stringify the value and assign a monkey patch to the function.

```js
console.log = (log => (...args) => {
    log(...args.map(v => typeof v === 'string' ? JSON.stringify(v) : v));
})(console.log);

console.log('test', 42);
```

Comment: How about calling .toString alone

`console.log(someNumber.toString());`

Answer (score 0):

Use the escape character \ for double quotes. For example,

`const test = "\"100\"";`

Now, `console.log(test)` will print "100" instead of 100.

I hope that helps!

Comment: It need to detect it if a variable is a string.

Comment: Didn't get your point? You want to print double quotes. Right? You can do that using escape character.

Comment: You can use `typeof variableName` to find whether it is a string or not. But, your original question doesn't implement that you wanted to check this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `typeof` with template literals:

```js
const test = "100";

if (typeof test == "string") {
  console.log(`"${test}"`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to include the *quotes*. Of course you'll need to check if it's a `string` first

```js
const someString = "100";
const someNumber = 100;

const includeQuotesIfString = x => typeof x === 'string' ? `"${x}"` : x;

console.log('before_string', someString);
console.log('after string', includeQuotesIfString(someString));
console.log('before number', someNumber);
console.log('after number', includeQuotesIfString(someNumber));
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you could also use [string substitutions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#Using_string_substitutions):

```js
const test = "100";

console.log('%o', test);
console.log('%o', 1);
```